# Check in MySQL table if my ID exist in the results

Tags: mysql, sql

How to check in MySQL table if my ID exist in the results and return TRUE, but this is a little complicated as I would like to check GROUP of records and not the last one from that GROUP, code below for the table and query which doesn't work, I would like to check if my `$session_user_id` exist in the GROUP OF `auction_bid_item_id` but not check last row as the last row is a WINNING ROW.

```
CREATE TABLE `auction_bids` (   
    `auction_bid_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    `auction_bid_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `auction_bid_seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   
    `auction_bid_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (`auction_bid_id`) 
);
```

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM auction_bids 
WHERE auction_bid_user_id = '$session_user_id' 
GROUP BY auction_bid_item_id;
```

Comment: You may receive the records in any order since there is no `order by` clause. How do you define the last row? Is it by `auction_bid_id`?

Comment: that how I am doing that: SELECT m1.*
FROM auction_bids m1 LEFT JOIN auction_bids m2
 ON (m1.auction_bid_item_id = m2.auction_bid_item_id AND m1.auction_bid_id  < m2.auction_bid_id)
WHERE m2.auction_bid_id IS NULL AND m1.auction_bid_status = 'ENDED'

Comment: probably `WHERE m2.auction_bid_id IS NULL` is `WHERE m2.auction_bid_id IS NOT NULL` right?

Comment: Can u pls provide some sample data in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd2f4/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join against a subselect which determines if the user is in that group.

Ie, the following will get you the bids and a field saying if the user is found.

```
SELECT auction_bids.*, IF(Sub1.auction_bid_item_id IS NULL, 'User not found', 'User found')
FROM auction_bids 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT auction_bid_item_id 
    FROM auction_bids 
    WHERE auction_bid_user_id = '$session_user_id'
) Sub1
ON auction_bids.auction_bid_item_id = Sub1.auction_bid_item_id
GROUP BY auction_bids.auction_bid_item_id
```

EDIT - try this to try and ignore the latest bid

```
SELECT auction_bids.*, IF(Sub1.auction_bid_item_id IS NULL, 'User not found', 'User found')
FROM auction_bids 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT auction_bids.auction_bid_item_id 
    FROM auction_bids 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT auction_bid_item_id, MAX(auction_bid_id) AS LastBid
        FROM auction_bids
        GROUP BY auction_bid_item_id
    ) Sub2
    ON auction_bids.auction_bid_item_id = Sub2.auction_bid_item_id
    AND auction_bids.auction_bid_id =  Sub2.LastBid
    WHERE Sub2.auction_bid_item_id IS NULL
    AND auction_bid_user_id = '$session_user_id'
) Sub1
ON auction_bids.auction_bid_item_id = Sub1.auction_bid_item_id
GROUP BY auction_bids.auction_bid_item_id
```

Comment: above code doesn't work: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ( Sub1 . auction_bid_item_id IS NULL , 'User not found' , 'User found' )  FRO' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, missed out the ON clause which is now added

Comment: testing it now, please bear with me

Comment: it does work, but is checking all of the rows from the group including the last one and I would like to avoid that one, so eliminate last row as the last row is a winning bid

Comment: how it should be is GROUP BY auction_bid_item_id NOT INCLUDE LAST ROW as last row is the winning row

Comment: Added a suggestion for that. Not tested though (no test data)

Comment: as you can see ID 8 is showing that EXIST but that is not true as only IDs: 1, 5 ,6 7 EXIST

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (with php)

```
$id_exists = false;

$id        = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$select    = "SELECT auction_bid_id FROM auction_bids WHERE auction_bid_id ='$id'";

$result    = mysql_query($select);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
   $id_exists = true;
}else{
   $id_exists = false;
}
```

Comment: nope :) above code is checking if Unique ID = $_GET['ID'], that's not my question sorry.